# Problema con web local en chrome sobre windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, windows10, chrome, google-chrome-app

Tengo una web dentro de mi red, que es un aplicativo y trae embebido un salvapantallas o presentación diseñado en `Flash`, que se ejecuta tras 1 minuto sin movimiento alguno. La llamo por un alias como `paginita` o por la `ip` correspondiente `130.20.10.50`, aunque en los 4 equipos donde se trabaja con ella, al loguearse al sistema, programe que se ejecutara el chrome con el modificador `--kiosk`, y queda la web a pantalla completa, funciona correctamente. El problema surge con `Windows 10`, tuve que cambiar obligado estos equipos y no doy con la solución. Cada vez que aparece el salvapantallas o presentación la pantalla se queda en negro ya que el chrome detecta el flash como no seguro. Claro que manualmente puedo permitir, clicando en el "!" donde dice No seguro, pero este cambio es temporal, y necesito que quede configurado así en forma permanente... o sea, que la ip `130.20.10.50` quede como Sitio Seguro y que permita visualizar el `flash`. He hecho cantidad de pruebas, pero ninguna resultó, solo me deja ver el `flash` temporalmente, lo cual no me sirve, ya que yo no tengo acceso cómodo y permanente a esos equipos.

Comment: fijate si alguna de estas opciones te sirve (edtas el acceso directo del chrome) https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: probaría con : `--allow-outdated-plugins --allow-running-insecure-content --disable-web-security ` y tal vez tengas que definir una carpeta para el perfil de usuario inseguro con `--user-data-dir`

Comment: probé con todo esto , me salio no se permite --disable-web-security porque genera inseguridad bla bla bla .... no probe lo ultimo de definir el perfil de usuario

Comment: me faltó mencionar que no funcionó

Comment: cuando incluyo alguno de los modificadores conteniendo "secure" "insecure" "security" , sale un mensaje del estilo "no se admite indicador de linea de comandos ya que compromete la seguridad y estabilidad" ..... ups

Comment: Varias opciones: ponele el `--user-data-dir` asi no toma el perfil actual, y revisar las opciones del primer enlace para ver que combinación te sirve. O ir por el lado administrador y setear politicas de grupo https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates , O dependiendo de cómo esté armado el flash convertirlo a javascript+html5 canvas (necesitas el .fla y alguna versión CS6 o superior del adobe )

Comment: No funcionó, seguiré buscando, gracias igual

Comment: Posiblemente una solucíon permanente -- se permita la IP aquí en esta URL chrome://settings/content/unsandboxedPlugins?search=plugin

Comment: gracias pero no funciona.

Comment: Esto no responde a tu pregunta, pero considera cambiar las animaciones en flash ya que la mayoría de los navegadores no lo soportan y Adobe dejará de darle soporte en 2020.

Comment: si claro, el tema es que a corto plazo no puedo cambiarlo.